# revert merge to master, keep feature branch changes, without changing history

Tags: git

I had a feature branch and a master branch. I did some work on the feature, merged into master, pushed the changes, and then deleted the feature branch, both remotely and locally. So far, so good.

After merging, I realized there was a problem with my feature changes. I'd like to undo the merge on master, but still keep the feature changes so I can work on them again. I don't want to rewrite the history of master because other people are working on it too. I think my best bet is to use `revert` to make new commits that undo the problem?

What I had originally:

```
A---B---C---D   [master]
     \      
      E----F    [feature]
```

What I have now:

```
A---B---C---D---E'---F' [master]
```

What I want:

```
A---B---C---D---E'---F'---RE'---RF'        [master]
                                 \
                                  E"---F"  [feature]
```

RE' reverts E' and RF' reverts F'. Meanwhile E" contains the same content as the original E and F" contains the same content as the original F.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Your diagrams could use a bit of work, because you've reserved the letter `E` to represent a commit whose parent is `B` in the first one, but used it to represent a commit whose parent is `D` in the second one. Perhaps you wanted that to be `E'`? (Or call the first `E`, `E0` instead?) If you use `E'` for the second diagram, you'll need `E''` or `E"` in the last (and then `feature` will need to point to `F'''` or `F"'`).

Comment: The commit content is the same between the E whose parent is B and the E whose parent is D. That's just what it looks like after it's been merged to master.

Comment: The *content* may be the same (it quite likely *isn't*), but the *parent link* is different. The commit is composed of—or perhaps a better way to put it is that its hash ID is determined by— *all* the bits that go into it. The true name of a commit is its hash ID; we should use a different symbol for different commits, lest we go insane trying to interpret and communicate about the resulting graph. :-)

Comment: edited the post for clarity, is that better?

Comment: Yep - will adapt to your updated symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, there are a lot of ways to do this.  Here is the command sequence I would most likley use given your desired final state—it ends up being just a hair different than what you drew:

1. `git checkout master` if needed, then `git revert HEAD~2..HEAD` to get:

   ```
   A--B--C--D--E'--F'--RF'--RE'   <-- master (HEAD)
   ```

   Note that `git revert` with a range backs commits out in reverse order.
2. `git checkout -b feature`:

   ```
   A--B--C--D--E'--F'--RF'--RE'  <-- master, feature (HEAD)
   ```
3. `git cherry-pick HEAD~4..HEAD~2`, to copy `E--F` again:

   ```
   A--B--C--D--E'--F'--RF'--RE'       <-- master
                             \
                              E"--F"  <-- feature (HEAD)
   ```

If it helps—with longer commit chains, it might—you can add temporary tags to various commits.  For instance, if you start with:

```
A--B--C--D--E'--F'   <-- master
```

and run:

```
git tag T1 HEAD~2; git tag T2 HEAD
```

you get:

```
        T1     T2
         |      |
         v      v
A--B--C--D--E'--F'   <-- master
```

So now you can use `T1..T2` everywhere to mean "commits `E'` and `F'`, so that the revert command becomes:

```
git revert T1..T2
```

and the cherry-pick becomes:

```
git cherry-pick T1..T2
```

Once you're done, you can delete the two temporary tags:

```
git tag -d T1 T2
```

as they were only there to remember the hash IDs of the two specific commits that delimit the range of "interesting" commits.  The relative names (`HEAD~2..HEAD` or `master~2..master`) change their numbering as you add more commits and cause the names to move as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Add revert commits to `master`

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD
git push
```

2. Re-create the `feature` branch

```
git checkout -b feature
```

3. Cherry-pick `feature` commits

```
git cherry-pick HEAD~4..HEAD~2
git push
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, after step 2, the head of [master] will be at RF' and the head of [feature] will be at F'. The `rebase` command will find the common ancestor of both branches, which is F'. Then it tries to find the new commits on [feature] since F', of which there are none. Finally, it moves the head of [feature] to the head of [master], and applies those diffs there... but since there aren't any, then we end up with [feature] just pointing at RF'?

Comment: Yes, I am used to doing this kind of thing by changing the history, `rebase` will be the wrong tool in this case. Should `cherry-pick` instead. Will update answer, will be mostly the same as @torek answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
# make sure you're working from master
git checkout master

# revert commits E and F
# (but in reverse chronological order is better to avoid unnecessary conflicts)
git revert F E
```

At this point your tree looks like

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---F'---E'        [master]

# then create your new branch
git checkout -b feature

# and here you might as well revert the reverts
git revert E' F'
```

to finally obtain

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---F'---E'        [master]
                              \
                               E''---F''   [feature]
```

---

But I'd suggest grouping `E` and `F` by using `-n` during the first revert (then you'll have to commit afterwards), it'll be easier at the next stages to revert the revert, and history will be much more readable. Like this :

```
git checkout master
git revert -n F E
# (at this point, if you had to resolve conflicts, don't forget to add them)
git commit
git checkout -b feature
git revert E'
```

and the final tree :

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---E'        [master]
                         \
                          E''     [feature]
```

(where in that last schema `E'` is the revertion of `E` *and* `F`)

Push all this only when you're satisfied with the whole situation.